# I have two cashier's checks and no account

Tags: banking, cashier-check

I have two pretty big cashier's checks. Can I go to Wal-Mart or any bank to cash them? Or start an account of wanted. One of the checks is from last month. Can I still use it? Would Wal-Mart even be able to cash a check that big?

Comment: Pretty big being $500 or $50,000?

Comment: The check from last month is still good. In the U.S., checks are good for at least six months.

Comment: 1600 something and 3200something

Comment: If you can go to the actual bank where the check originated i.e. Chase, Wells Fargo, they can typically cash it somewhat easily (not the specific branch, just the provider). You definitely need to provide a photo ID like a driver's license, but sometimes also your SSN and some other info for large cash values for AML compliance.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I go to Wal-Mart or any bank to cash them?
>
> Would Wal-Mart even be able to cash a check that big?

**Yes**. [Walmart](https://www.walmart.com/cp/check-cashing/632047) will cash cashier's checks up to $5,000 year-round for a $6 fee in every state but NY, NJ, and RI. Keep in mind that you can cash this at any other place which cashes normal checks. You could also open a checking account at any bank in order to have them cash it.

> One of the checks is from last month. Can I still use it?

Look for an expiration date on the check. For example, it may have "Void After 90 Days" printed on it somewhere. Odds are that it has not expired after a month, however.